# Android half screen activity

Tags: android

I want to create activity with one button. When you click on the button, half screen layout appears from bottom.
[image]

And more when you click on background layout, new front background disappear.

Do you have an idea who to implement this?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I have found solution for this feature.
Firstly, I make new hidden view below the screen( You can found how from the answers below).

And then, I animate on button click with the following  code:

```
dialog.animate().translationY(-HEIGHT).setDuration(TIME);
```

Comment: I would suggest using a view (whatever kind of layout you think would be best for its contents) with a translationY value that makes it offscreen. then you could use a valueanimator or something similar to bring it up and down smoothly and trigger them with your desired inputs

Comment: Would you provide me some more detailed instructions, how to set view outside of screen and who to animate moving from bottom?

Comment: This question shows little to no effort.

Comment: Well, I don't think so. I have tried searching through Android API documentation about some kind of element or anything like that, because I have found many apps with this feature.

Comment: I think what you want to use is Bottom Sheet view from the design support library. Here is a tutorial which explains how to use it: http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-material-design-bottom-sheets-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<!-- view with button -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/task_list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>

<!-- example content hided in bottom -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_your_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/minus_height_of_your_content"
    >
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To show hide content change it marginBottom. In start marginBotton should be - of this layout height to be out of screen. You can do it using animation  on translateY and on end change marginBottom to finish value. This is one of possible solutions.

Comment: How can I detect click on background layer?

Comment: Set it an id and findElementById and set OnClickListener then do backward animation for second/upper view.